# Finding the standard form of a Möbius transformation

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

Consider the Möbius transformation $m(z)=\dfrac{(az+b)}{(cz+d)}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers such that $ad-bc$ is nonzero and $m$ is normalized so that $ad-bc=1.$

Assuming that m is elliptic, we have the function $\text{τ}(m)=(a+d)^2$ in between $[0,4),$ then $m$ has the standard form $ρz$ where $ρ$ is a complex number with $ |ρ|=1.$

If $m$ is loxodromic, then $m$ has the standard form $ρz$ where again $ρ$ is a complex number with $|ρ|>1$ or $|ρ|<1.$

My question is that how do we find $ρ$ so that we can find the standard form of $m$?

Comment: Do you mean $({\rm tr}\, m)^2=(a+d)^2$?

Comment: Actually, yes it is related to the trace function. I thought that it is defined that way, but the notation for that function is the Greek letter tau.

Comment: If $m$ is conjugate to ${\rm diag}(\lambda,\lambda^{-1})$, you can solve the quadratic equation $\lambda+\lambda^{-1}={\rm tr}\,m$.

Comment: I think I got it, but there is only one problem. When you solve it you have two different such multipliers. Does it really matter which one I choose?

Comment: No, because the standard form is not unique: $\rho z$ and $\rho^{-1} z$ are conjugate via the transformation $-1/z$. I can write an answer.

Comment: I got the point, thanks.